# How to use ToolTip for DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a popup that appears when the user overlaps the mouse in a cell. I've seen some online tutorials and I created a ToolTip this:

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
       <Style>
         <Setter Property="DataGridCell.ToolTip">
               <Setter.Value>bb</Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
       </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'position'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Pos." Width="*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'teamName'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Squadra" Width="*" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'points'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Punti"  Width="*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'playedGames'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Giocate"  Width="*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goals'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Goal fatti" Width="*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goalsAgainst'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Goal subiti" Width="*"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goalDifference'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Differenza reti" Width="*"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

the only problem is that I do not understand how to show the full text of a single cell when the user overlaps with the mouse on it. Particularly when the DataGrid is minimum resolution of the header cells are not shown completely, and that is a problem, to avoid this I would make sure that if it is the user overlaps the mouse on "pos", then it is the showed the complete header as tooltip is "position". How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**For DataGrid Cells:**

If you want a ToolTip that shows the full content of a particular DataGrid cell when the mouse is over it, you can modify your `DataGridTextColumn` and use the same Binding for the ToolTip:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'position'}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Pos." Width="*">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path = 'position'}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Or, if you want to set it once for all the columns, you can bind to the Text property of the `DataGridTextColumn`'s content:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

**For DataGrid Column Headers:**

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Yes, but I mean, you can do this for the other columns in the DataGrid without creating x ToolTip for x columns?

Comment: Yes you can. You can modify your `DataGrid.CellStyle` as above. I edited the answer to include this alternative.

Comment: Hmm, so your DataGrid cell has data but, the ToolTip does not show up?

Comment: Yes, but when I start the program my DataGrid doesn't have any data yet. I want only show the header text complete when the mouse is over the header

Comment: Oh, I think I may have misunderstood the question. So you need the ToolTip for the headers, not the cell with data? If so, I have added the solution for header in the answer.